# ANDROID: App not responding on Inserting Data

Tags: java, android

I am very new to Android Programming, and I have a difficulty of inserting a data. When ever I submit the form, app force closes, prompting an error **"App not Responding"**

I made a Java class named `DB_Controller`

```
    package com.techdepot_ph.maco.secretjournal;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Maco on 18-Jan-17.
 */
public class DB_Controller extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DB_Controller(Context context) {
        super(context, "app.db", null, 1);
    }

    //This creates the database
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE STORIES( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "uniq_id TEXT, " +
                "title TEXT, " +
                "body TEXT, " +
                "is_private INT, '" +
                "dev_id TEXT, " +
                "user_id TEXT, " +
                "date_time TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STORIES");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //This inserts the Data in the Database
    public void insert_story(String story_title, String story_body) {
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("title", story_title);
        content.put("body", story_body);      

        this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow("STORIES", "", content);


    }
```

In my Activity class

```
package com.techdepot_ph.maco.secretjournal;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StoryCreate_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DB_Controller db;
    EditText story_title, story_body;
    //Switch is_private;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_create_);


        story_title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.story_title);
        story_body = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.story_body);
        //is_private = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.story_private);


    }

    public  void btn_click(View view) {
        db = new DB_Controller(this);
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.story_submit:
                    db.insert_story(story_title.getText().toString(), story_body.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(StoryCreate_Activity.this, "Data Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;


        }
    }
}
```

In my layout, I defined the button `R.id.story_submit` to call the `btn_click()` onClick.

Comment: found some issue in your create table query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the issue in your create table query.

**Previously:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE STORIES( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "uniq_id TEXT, " +
            "title TEXT, " +
            "body TEXT, " +
            "is_private INT, '" +
            "dev_id TEXT, " +
            "user_id TEXT, " +
            "date_time TEXT)");
}
```

**Update to:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE STORIES( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "uniq_id TEXT, " +
            "title TEXT, " +
            "body TEXT, " +
            "is_private INTEGER, " +
            "dev_id TEXT, " +
            "user_id TEXT, " +
            "date_time TEXT)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE STORIES( " +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "uniq_id TEXT, " +
            "title TEXT, " +
            "body TEXT, " +
            "is_private INTEGER, " +
            "dev_id TEXT, " +
            "user_id TEXT, " +
            "date_time TEXT)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do call insert data to database on background thread, not call direct on main thread. You can use Thread, AsyncStack to do that.

Comment: How do you do this properly? I'm really new to android

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lot of different issues with your application code, you will need to **submit the error log generated** at the bottom to know the cause of ANR (Application Not Responding) error which Android will shut down your app if it doesn't respond within 5 seconds.

Looking at your code, you have only 2 fields that require to be inserted into the Database story_title, story_body and the rest are redundant except for _id which is a auto incremented key.

There is afew things I can pick up by glancing at your app:

- Wrong data type use **Integer** instead of **Int** for SQLite
- Wrong
  semantic **is_private INTEGER** when we use is_ we refer to **BOOLEAN**
  True/False
- Make it small remove the code you are not using and just stick to the 2 fields

So even when fixing this you might still run into an Error, without the log we can't point out further, I created a similar app that might help you to understand on how to handle database in Android https://github.com/alkathirikhalid/Recipe-App

This app doesn't run background task, preferably to handle database on a different thread but for elaboration this will definitely help.